# Distributed batch normalization

Tags: tensorflow

I have a deep neural net duplicated across multiple GPUs for training, as in the tensorflow CIFAR10 tutorial. How can I add in batch normalization when each GPU can see only a portion of each batch?

Comment: The simplest thing is to just normalize on per-GPU basis (what Torch [does](https://github.com/torch/nn/issues/1071) ). Someone wrote some code to do it across GPUs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7439).

Comment: Since doing it on per-GPU basis makes batches smaller, it could make sense to use batch [renormalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03275.pdf) which is supposed to be better than batch normalization. Implementation by Yuxin [here](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/blob/3f238a015b941041e58ed43e63d5306dbae979fc/tensorpack/models/batch_norm.py#L208)